# Running Vaadin Flow beverage-starter-flow with standalone jetty does not work

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10, vaadin-flow

Launching [beverage-starter-flow](https://github.com/vaadin/beverage-starter-flow) with `mvn jetty:run` then it works just fine. But if download same version of Jetty (9.4.11.v20180605) and launch it through IntelliJ IDEA then I get the following error.

How to fix this? Should skeleton-starter-flow work with standalone Jetty?

```
here was an exception while trying to navigate to '' with the exception message 'Unable to create an instance of 'com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.views.reviewslist.ReviewsList'. The constructor threw an exception.'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create an instance of 'com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.views.reviewslist.ReviewsList'. The constructor threw an exception.
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.ReflectTools.createProxyInstance(ReflectTools.java:512)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.ReflectTools.createInstance(ReflectTools.java:449)
    at com.vaadin.flow.di.DefaultInstantiator.getOrCreate(DefaultInstantiator.java:64)
    at com.vaadin.flow.di.Instantiator.createRouteTarget(Instantiator.java:157)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.lambda$getRouteTarget$1(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:115)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.getRouteTarget(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:114)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.handle(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:166)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.handleNavigation(Router.java:201)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:172)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.initializeUI(Router.java:93)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.createAndInitUI(BootstrapHandler.java:1050)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(BootstrapHandler.java:393)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1493)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:300)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor19.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45005)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.ReflectTools.createProxyInstance(ReflectTools.java:481)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't find resource 'frontend://src/views/reviewslist/reviews-list.html' via the servlet context
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.DefaultTemplateParser.getTemplateContent(DefaultTemplateParser.java:104)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.TemplateDataAnalyzer.parseTemplate(TemplateDataAnalyzer.java:185)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.TemplateInitializer.<init>(TemplateInitializer.java:93)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.PolymerTemplate.<init>(PolymerTemplate.java:97)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.PolymerTemplate.<init>(PolymerTemplate.java:112)
    at com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.views.reviewslist.ReviewsList.<init>(ReviewsList.java:74)
    ... 55 more
```

Comment: How are you launching jetty in IntelliJ? If you go to the Maven panel and run Jetty -> run from within IntelliJ, then it would be the same as running it from the terminal.

Comment: @JensJansson I am adding new configuration in Run/Debug Configurations dialog. It is "local" configuration with default configuration. Deployment is beveragebuddy:war. I tried reproducing the problem with my own computer and same setup is working fine. Maybe office laptop failed to download some dependency, but why wouldn't maven build fail to download...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running Jetty or Tomcat from IntelliJ did not copy frontend folder from webapp sources to `target/beveragebuddy-1.0-SNAPSHOT/frontend/`. Running `mvn package` fixed this.